# Не могу разобрать что делает код

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

typedef int type;
typedef std::vector<type> vt;

type find_min(vt arr)
{
    type min = arr[0];
    for(auto it = arr.begin() + 1; it != arr.end(); ++it)
        if(min > *it) min = *it;

    return min;
}

type find_max(vt arr)
{
    type max = arr[0];
    for(auto it = arr.begin() + 1; it != arr.end(); ++it)
        if(max < *it) max = *it;

    return max;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> arr;
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    while(n--)
    {
        int temp;
        std::cin >> temp;
        arr.push_back(temp);
    }

    type min = find_min(arr);
    type max = find_max(arr);

    std::for_each(arr.begin(), arr.end(),
                  [&](auto& i) { i = ( i == max ?  min : ( i == min ? max : i )); } );

    for(auto i : arr) std::cout << i << " ";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Всем привет, нашел код в интернете и понять не могу строчки :

```
std::for_each(arr.begin(), arr.end(),
[&](auto& i) { i = ( i == max ?  min : ( i == min ? max : i )); } );
```

То что он пробегается по вектору понятно, но что написано в следующей строчке вообще не понятно.
Объясните пожалуйста как это можно записать на "нормальном" языке, чтобы было понятно новичку.

Задача - https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread2818672.html#post15439256

Comment: Нормальным языком, это посоветовать прочитать про тернарные выражения.

Comment: я понять не могу что значит [&](auto& i) и что оно делает

Comment: @こきん не только тернарные, но ещё и про лямбды.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::for_each(arr.begin(), arr.end(),
```

Для всех элементов `arr` выполняется лямбда-функция

```
    [&](auto& i) { i = ( i == max ?  min : ( i == min ? max : i )); } );
```

Каковая получает ссылку на элемент вектора, так что может его менять, что и делает:

```
i = ( i == max ?  min : ( i == min ? max : i ));
```

Если `i == max` - присваивает `i` значение `min`, в противном случае, если
`i == min` - присваивает `i` значение `max`, в противном случае не делает ничего, оставляя значение `i` неизменным.

Т.е. все `max` меняет на `min` и наоборот.

*как это можно записать на "нормальном" языке* - вот так, например:

```
for(auto it = arr.begin(), it != arr.end(); ++it)
    if (*it == max) *it = min;
        else if (*it == min) *it = max;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, не знаю какой раз вы уже выручаете